# How to get local network device Host name in android application

Tags: android, network-programming

Hi I can find local network  active devices list of IP and MAC address but not getting Host name using Ip or MAC plz any body tell what I need to do to find host name

I use

```
 InetAddress inetAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2");
 String hostname = inetAddr.getHostName();            
 System.out.println("Hostname: " + hostname);
O/p:-
Hostname:192.168.1.2
```

I want name of that device  any other way to get that user details uising arp or else

Comment: if I use  InetAddress.getLocalHost(); it gives me proper name

Answer (score -2):

To get MAC address please use this-

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String address = info.getMacAddress();
```

Permission needed for MAC address-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

To get IP Address

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

Permission needed for IP address

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I already got  my device IP and Mac but I want all Host name device connected in my LAN